# Why I am getting no authentication token error?

Tags: symfony

I have the folowing snippet of code to check use role however it returns me with a

> The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.

```
public function loginAction(){
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();
        var_dump($this->get("security.context")->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'));
        $response =  new Response();
        $response -> setContent("login facebook");
        $response->send();
        return array('name'=>'login facebook');
    }
```

Why I am getting this error and how do I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception message is pretty clear: `One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL`. To check user role, you need a token which contains a user (anonymous or not). By default, if you don't configure a authentication provider for a given path, you won't get any security context.

The solution here is to add an authentication provider.